# Update values in evenly spaced mesh with slider

Tags: python, numpy, mesh, ipywidgets

The problem I'm facing is that I'm unable to figure out how to update the figure when I increase/decrease values with my slider.

I am creating an x, y mesh grid, then plotting it, and updating the values within my array to define a new mesh. I would like to be able to move the slider and see a finer/coarser grid and update the plot and axes.

Additionally, I would like the user to be able to move the grid lines interactively with the mouse. This is not included in example code. Does someone know how to implement this?

There are similar questions that have been asked about updating values on a plot with a slider, but perhaps none address this specific problem; can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? I realize I don't have anything that is redrawing the plot (though I have tested various things), but am unsure how to implement this, as M.plotGrid() creates the grid, so it may/may not be as easy as using fig.canvas.draw_idle().

Here is my code:

```
#Create simple evenly spaced mesh and allow slider to change values

from SimPEG import Mesh, np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider, Button, RadioButtons

hx = np.r_[0.1,0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]
hy = np.r_[0.1,0.1,0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1]

M = Mesh.TensorMesh([hx, hy])
M.plotGrid()

#Define slider location, size, and color for adjusting mesh values
axhx = plt.axes([0.25, 0.1, 0.65, 0.03])
axhy = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
xnode_inc = Slider(axhx, 'X mesh Node', 0.1, 1000.0, valinit=0)
anode_inc = Slider(axhy, 'Y mesh Node', 0.1, 1000.0, valinit=0)

def update(val):
    framehx = xnode_inc.val + hx
    framehy = ynode_inc.val + hy
    M = Mesh.TensorMesh([framehx, framehy])
    print M, framehx, framehy
    M.plotGrid()

xnode_inc.on_changed(update)
ynode_inc.on_changed(update)

plt.show()
```

Comment: I can't see  a problem in the code. All elements of setting sliders are there (axes, slider, update func, on_changed event, show). Using the sliders in ipywidgets in the new Ipython/Jupyter notebooks is much simplified. Would that be OK? Also could you come up with an example that doesn't depend on `SimPEG`, just `numpy`? The problem might be `np.around`, btw. try `np.around(sx,decimals=1)`.

Comment: `np.around(sx) --> ..(sx.val)` I think

Comment: Looking at this more I think my problem might be what to define l as. I put sx.val and sy.val in the np.around. Let me see if I can conjure up something without SimPEG, though if you have matplotlib, numpy, scipy, and cython, adding SimPEG is very simple using pip/git.

Comment: I didn't change the example to something just containing numpy but implemented some changes that now update the values within the array when the slider is moved. My only issue now is that it isn't updating the graph as the values are changed. Any ideas where the issue might be?

Comment: @roadrunner66 would you be able to conjure up and example using ipywidgets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only give an example of interactively changing a `numpy` grid as I don't use `SimPEG`. The example is in an Ipython/Jupyter notebook. This is by far the simplest way today to generate interactive sliders, pulldowns, radiobuttons etc, i.e. much improved over the complex setup of similar setup with the original matplotlib sliders. I threw in a combo-box for the colormap just to simplicity of it.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as p
from ipywidgets import *
%matplotlib inline


def gridandplot(dx,mp):
    x=np.arange(0,5,dx)
    y=np.arange(0,5,dx)
    x,y=np.meshgrid(x,y)
    z= np.sin(x)* np.cos(y)
    if mp=='gray':
        cmap=p.cm.gray
    else:
        cmap= p.cm.jet
    p.imshow(z,interpolation='none',cmap=cmap)

interact(gridandplot, dx=(0.005,0.2,0.001), mp= ('gray','jet'))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would be interested in using ipywidgets/jupyter if they are easier. I tried installing them and am getting this error: traitlets.traitlets.TraitError: The 'kernel' trait of a Comm instance must be a Kernel, but a value of type 'NoneType' (i.e. None) was specified. Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Haven't seen that. So you start the notebook with 'ipython notebook' or 'jupyter notebook' and you get the webpage, right? At what point do you get the error? Does say, the import numpy statement work?

Comment: If I type jupiter notebook in the terminal I get the webpage. I can pull up the script but I don't know how to run it from the notebook. I get the kernel error when I type python script.py in the terminal.

Comment: You just paste the lines into the notebook. It's just one cell.

Comment: I figured out that the issue was that my kernel was dead. I tested it again and this works nicely. I am still trying to fudge my example into interactive to get it to work as I would like. I was also able to solve the issue of updating the graph with the matplotlib slider. I am trying interactive to see what might be easier.

Comment: I have the same problem as @user1332577. I have not yet resolved it, but I found this in an ipywidgets manual "The widget framework is built on top of the Comm framework (short for communication). The Comm framework is a framework that allows the kernel to send/receive JSON messages to/from the front end." [link](http://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Custom.html#Import-jupyter-js-widgets). Any suggestions?

Comment: I wasn't aware of  the pages you linked when I wrote the answer. ipywidgets works out of the box w/o any Javascript knowledged required. I'm not sure what you mean when you say you have the same problem, when @user1332577  didn't use the ipywidgets at all. Can you post your problem?